# Use common latex quotes with csquote in french mode and keeping specific highlight in SublimeText

Tags: highlighting, csquotes, sublime-text

I'm using Sublime Text3 with Latexing, and i search to know if it's possible to replace automatically during compilation the regular quote for latex `''mytext""` by `\enquote{}`

That seems silly but, a) if i want to display french quotes, and not english quote "",  i need to use csquote. b) If i use csquote i need to to write `\enquote{}` and in consequence, **i lost the pretty highlighting** for this specific syntax `''mytext""`

So i search to keep the pretty highlight with csquotes package in french mode, do you think it's possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in `Preferences > Package Settings > LaTeXing > Keybindings - Default` you'll find this key binding:

```
{
    "keys": ["\""],
    "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "``$0''"},
    "context": [
      {"key": "eol_selector", "match_all": true, "operand": "comment.line.percentage", "operator": "not_equal"},
      {"key": "selection_empty", "match_all": true, "operand": true, "operator": "equal"},
      {"key": "selector", "operand": "text.tex.latex", "operator": "equal"},
      {"key": "selector", "operand": "source.r", "operator": "not_equal"},
      {"key": "selector", "operand": "meta.block.parameters.knitr", "operator": "not_equal"},
      {"key": "selector", "operand": "meta.block.parameters.knitr", "operator": "not_equal"},
      {"key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operand": true, "operator": "equal"}
    ]
},
```

which is the one responsible for the autocomplete.

If you put the following

```
{
    "keys": ["\""],
    "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "\\enquote{$0}"},
    "context": [
      {"key": "eol_selector", "match_all": true, "operand": "comment.line.percentage", "operator": "not_equal"},
      {"key": "selection_empty", "match_all": true, "operand": true, "operator": "equal"},
      {"key": "selector", "operand": "text.tex.latex", "operator": "equal"},
      {"key": "selector", "operand": "source.r", "operator": "not_equal"},
      {"key": "selector", "operand": "meta.block.parameters.knitr", "operator": "not_equal"},
      {"key": "selector", "operand": "meta.block.parameters.knitr", "operator": "not_equal"},
      {"key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operand": true, "operator": "equal"}
    ]
},
```

in your User Keybindings (from Preferences) you obtain what you asked.

As for the syntax highlighting, it can be done but you need to modify the `.tmLanguage` file of LaTeXing, which is more complicated and can potentially break with updates of the package. The idea would be to assign the `string` scope to the parameter of `\enquote`.